# PCA - intuitive explanation

Tags: linear-algebra

About PCA, my book says the following:

"Another way of looking at principal components is in terms of the variance of the data. If we were to project the data on to the first principal axis (htat is, the vector defining the first principal component), then the variation in the direction of the first principal component is proportional to the sum of the squares of the distances from the second principal axis. Similarly, the variance along the second principal axis is proportional to the sum of the squares of the perpendicular distances from the first principal axis. Now, since the total sum of squares is a constant, then minimising the sum of squared distance from a  given line is the same as maximising the sum of squares from its perpendicular or, by the above, maximising the variance in the direction of the line."

Could someone help me better understand the last sentence? A graphic explanation would also be appreciated.

Thank you.